# Ember.js - Rendering additional data for a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an `app` model and apps have an `id` and `name`.

```
  this.resource("apps", function() {
    this.route('show', { path: ':app_id' });
  });
```

I'd like to make the `show` view show metrics about the app, but the query is pretty intense, so I don't want to include it in the call to the `index` view (let's say this is a table).

I'm not sure if this is possible with ember-data because the `app` would already be in the store with the simplified payload and not be re-requested for the `show` view to get the metrics.

Then my head went to making metrics a completely different model accessible from `apps/1/metrics` and then making it another model and everything.

But if I sideload the data, i have to provide ID references to the `metrics` for a particular `app`. And it's `hasOne` so there's not really IDs as there would be for a database backed model.

What's the best way to load in additional data about a model or expand the information supplied in the show view?

The backend is Rails and this is an ember-cli project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to retrieve the data in the `Route`'s `afterModel` handler:

```
var ShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // Load the model and return it.
    // This will only fire if the model isn't passed.
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    // Load the rest of the data based on the model and return it.
    // This fires every time the route re-loads (wether passed in or via model method).
  }
});
```

Comment: Gotcha. So that would be for if I wanted to have that extra query to get metrics all within the "show" route, right?

Comment: @brandonhilkert - Correct. You would load the original model in the `model` handler and then any extra data based on the model in `afterModel`.